# android convert date string to time in milliseconds

Tags: android, date, datetime

good morning,

i have this date as a String:

```
2016-05-20 00:00:00
```

now i would like to convert this string in a date format and to milliseconds.

i tried this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");

Date convertedDate = new Date();
try {
       convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_MHD)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> Wed Jan 20 00:00:00 MEZ 2016

but how can i convert this date now to milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **MM** for month.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

and to get Time use [Date.getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) method.

for more information take a look at [Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: ahhh that was my mistake. i tried convertedDate.getTime() - but this value can not be the correct value. but with MM it works fine !. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
long timeInMilliseconds = convertedDate .getTime();
Log.d("time in millisecond",""+timeInMilliseconds );
```